# SOLR Case Insensitive Field search issue

Tags: search, solr, case-insensitive

What I want to achieve is when I search after `test` to bring me also `Test, TeSt, TesT,TEST` with case insensitive search.
What should I do ?

I have this `textgen` type in my schema.xml that is assigned to `test_field`

```
<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="select">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here are the results which I want to recieve with my query.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"test_field:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"change.me",
        "test_field":["test"],
        "_version_":1546932094148542464},
      {
        "id":"change.me1",
        "test_field":["tesT"],
        "_version_":1546932100203020288},
      {
        "id":"change.me2",
        "test_field":["TesT"],
        "_version_":1546932103122255872},
      {
        "id":"change.me3",
        "test_field":["TEsT"],
        "_version_":1546932107768496128},
      {
        "id":"change.me4",
        "test_field":["TEST"],
        "_version_":1546932111283322880}]
  }}
```

When I use this query it does not give any result because it is case sensitive, even though it has the filter **LowerCaseFilterFactory**

`http://localhost:8983/solr/test-data/select?q=test_field:*test*&wt=json&indent=true`

AND the empty results. (what I'm doing wrong?)

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"test_field:*test*",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"change.me",
        "test_field":["test"],
        "_version_":1546932094148542464}]
  }}
```

Comment: You need to re index the document after adding filters. So please check the query after re indexing the document.

Comment: I've created a new schema and it worked, I think something was messed up in my old solr schema.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually putting stars (wildcards) at both ends of your search term? You should not need to do that. The whole point of Solr configuration is to tokenize your text in a way that you can just search for words without wildcards.

If you just search for a work in your text, it should work including mixed-case matching. If not, check that your field is actually mapped to the right type and that you reindexed. If still confused, Solr Admin UI has an analyze screen where you can select your fields (or your field types) and see how something is tokenized and how it is matched. You can experiment there.

Comment: I've created a new schema and it worked, I think something was messed up in my old solr schema.